# background-image "cover" white space on android chrome

Tags: html, css, angularjs

this bug is driving me nuts!

I have a website where I placed a background image on the body element and did the usual no-repeat center center fixed cover stuff,  It looks fine on every browswer I have tried except android chrome so far,  On android chrome it seems to give the home page some scrolling and you can show white space several hundred pixels high.  It works on chrome desktop, and even the various android dev tool simulators.

Here is the CSS I'm using -

```
body {
  background-color: transparent !important;
  background: url('../../images/pagesbackground.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

I've tried this same css on the HTML element as well to no avail (with a combination of height: 100vh / 100% on both body and or html element).  I've also tried taking off the background attachment-fixed, but then on other pages it doesnt scroll down for the content that expands down.  I'm using bootstrap, and Angular to serve each page as a template.  This is the index.html that serves the templates in the ng-view.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Goldbee Dev</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dist/styles/all.min.css">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster|Roboto|Titillium+Web|Rock+Salt|Condiment|Mate+SC|Pacifico|Luckiest+Guy' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"> </script>
</head>
<body ng-app="app">


    <div ng-view></div>








<script src="vendor/angular.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="dist/scripts/all.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I've also tried just making the background image a div that contains the ng-view and doing the same thing with no success.  Anyone have suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

One bandaid I used for now (as the site is live) - I made it the background of the HTML element again, and made the height 200%.  It prevents the whitespace but it scrolls down into a lot of empty area if you scroll down now.  Is there a way to prevent scrolling on the home page without JS or Jquery (I know how to code in those, but looking for the simplest method possible).